# How to catch an Exception and a SocketTimeOut Exception in one try/catch block

Tags: java

I have implemented a try catch block for URLconnection as well as Parser class as follow.

```
try {
    Url uri = new Url(urlString);
    Parser parse = new Parser(uri);
} catch (Exception  e)
{
    //ignore some other exceptions
}
catch (SocketTimeOutException  e)
{
    //I want to catch this exception and do some thing or restart
    //if it's a timeout issue.
    //I am using a proxy for the network connection at JVM setting
    //using setProperty    
}
```

So , my question is how to act accordingly based on the SocketTimeOutException case , and for other Exception ignore .

Thanks ,

Comment: You can only place a catch (Exception  e) { ... } after all other Exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As java specification says (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20), first matched, first executed.

Simply invert your catch clause :

```
try {
Url uri = new Url(urlString);
Parser parse = new Parser(uri);
} catch (SocketTimeOutException  e) {
//I want to cache this ecption and do some thing or  restart based 
//if its timeout issue
//am using  proxy for the network connection at JVM setting
//using setProperty
} catch (Exception  e) {
//ingnore some other excpetions
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put more specific exception types above more general types, so put the `SocketTimeoutException` catch clause above `Exception`

Answer (score 1):

Catch the SocketTimeOutException first:

```
try {
    // do stuff
} catch (SocketTimeOutException e) {
    // restart or do whatever you need to do
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to catch an Exception and a SocketTimeOut Exception in one try/catch block?? If you wan't to have only one catch block then you can do like this

```
try {
            URI uri = new URI(urlString);
            Parser parse = new Parser(uri);

            } catch(Exception e) {              
                if (e instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
```

Comment: very elegeant  , becuse you know i was also looking for that before. +1

Comment: yes... but recommended way is to catch exceptions with multiple blocks. Since question states "1 try/catch" I answered like this.

Comment: What's elegant about it? This is terrible, you're going to do something just because the exception class' name ends with SocketTimeoutException? That doesn't mean anything at all. And what if the exception thrown extends SocketTimeoutException and the class name ends with SomethingElseException?

Comment: How can SocketTimeoutException in java ends with Something else?? we know that it's existing,so we are doing that approach.

Comment: `public class SomethingElseException extends SocketTimeoutException {}`

Comment: I will agree with you. But I answered as per the question, it states "1 try/catch" and we know that we are throwing SocketTimeoutExeption.

Comment: Testing class by there names is terrific !! Better use instanceof